# How to handle python unicode string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, django-templates

A dict in which the string values are unicode string like `{'name': u'nav', 'school': u'mps'}`

In **javascript**, i'm trying access that dict like

```
<script>
var poi = {{ dict }}  ........... //Line #1
alert( poi.name )
</script>
```

while rending the html page line #1 is rendered as (error):

```
{'lastname': u'yadav', 'age': 23, 'id': 2, 'firstname': u'sahenky'}
```

One python solution is to encode the unicode string into some other format like ascii or utf-8(preferred)

```
str = u'nav'
str.encode('utf-8, 'ignore')
>>str
nav
```

Is there any elegant way to encode unicode string in python or javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the actual dict to the template, JSON encode it first:

```
import json
json.dumps(dict)
```